# optimising an SQL query that calculates averages for every minute of the day

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, bulkinsert

I have written an SQL routine to calculate average values for each minute of the day from 5 days data (the days are arguments for the routine) and insert the results into another table. It's quite long and I was wondering if there are any ways to optimize it.

The values I need to take to calculate the average are all in the same table SiteReading  so to get the 5 values for the same minute but from different days I join the table's subsets for those days so the hour and the minute would match and then the values end up on the same row. Then I add the 5 values on each row and make a new table out of that and insert it into Baseline table that stores those averages.

Here's the routine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'calc_baseline` (IN `input_site_id` int, IN `day1` varchar(12), IN `day2` varchar(12), IN `day3` varchar(12), IN `day4` varchar(12), IN `day5` varchar(12))
BEGIN

insert into Baseline
SELECT 
    site_id,
    contract_id,
    temp_time as timestamp,
    (sr1value + sr2value + sr3value + sr4value + sr5value) / 5 as value,
    programme
FROM
    (SELECT 
        distinct concat(cast(hour(temp_time) as char), ':', cast(minute(temp_time) as char)) as hourminute,            
            SR.site_id as site_id,
            value as sr1value,
            temp_time,
            S.contract_id as contract_id,
            programme
    FROM
        SiteReading SR
    join Site S ON SR.site_id = S.site_id
    join Contract C ON S.contract_id = C.contract_id
    where
        temp_time like 'day1%'
            and SR.site_id = input_site_id) sr1
        join
    (SELECT 
        concat(cast(hour(temp_time) as char), ':', cast(minute(temp_time) as char)) as hourminute,
            value as sr2value
    FROM
        SiteReading
    where
        temp_time like 'day2%'
            and site_id = input_site_id) sr2 ON sr1.hourminute = sr2.hourminute
        join
    (SELECT 
        concat(cast(hour(temp_time) as char), ':', cast(minute(temp_time) as char)) as hourminute,
            value as sr3value
    FROM
        SiteReading
    where
        temp_time like 'day3%'
            and site_id = input_site_id) sr3 ON sr1.hourminute = sr3.hourminute
        join
    (SELECT 
        concat(cast(hour(temp_time) as char), ':', cast(minute(temp_time) as char)) as hourminute,
            value as sr4value
    FROM
        SiteReading
    where
        temp_time like 'day4%'
            and site_id = input_site_id) sr4 ON sr1.hourminute = sr4.hourminute
        join
    (SELECT 
        concat(cast(hour(temp_time) as char), ':', cast(minute(temp_time) as char)) as hourminute,
            value as sr5value
    FROM
        SiteReading
    where
        temp_time like 'day5%'
            and site_id = input_site_id) sr5 ON sr1.hourminute = sr5.hourminute
limit 1440;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

---

The relevant tables that it's reading from and writing to are:

**- SiteReading:**

```
CREATE TABLE `SiteReading` (
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`,`temp_time`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`),
  KEY `contract_id` (`contract_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `SiteReading_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `Site` (`site_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `SiteReading_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`contract_id`) REFERENCES `Contract` (`contract_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

**- Baseline:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Baseline` (
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contract_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `programme` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

1. Because I need to get some additional values (site_id, contract_id, programme) to store in the Baseline that are the same for each row I was wondering that maybe I should do the insert statement in some other way? the thing is that all of the Baseline table's columns can not be null.
2. Maybe someone has any other comments about this procedure - do I need to define some other parameters for this routine like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or some other routine related things?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say the query is 'long', is that a reference to the actual length of the script itself, or the time it takes to execute? If script length is a concern you're essentially duplicating the same query five times, might want to put that in a UDF or View.

Comment: it takes approx 10 seconds to execute from the outside client application (mySQL workbench) - probably because SiteReading table is very very big. The java application that is going to call it will run on the same machine as the server and will use localhost as IP so it might be faster. Java app needs to do this routine several hundreds of times once daily so I am a bit concerned - that's why I was asking for help optimizing it. Thanks for the advice on storing the repetitive subset retrieve statement as a UDF - I will work on that.

Comment: Ok, so performance *is* the issue. In that case while I am having a little bit of an issue groking the script, I think the root is the duplication of the query. You are querying the same table 5 times and joining the results. Why not run one query and use an OR syntax? 

    temp_time like 'day2%' OR temp_time like 'day3%' ...

Then instead of the additive part of the parent query, use the SUM() function which is much more optimal.

Comment: big thanks for the help, I'll do just that and see how it works out.

Comment: What's the deal with the seconds on the timestamps?  Are they always `00` or some other value?  If so, the query could be much faster by grouping by the timestamp instead of the very slow `LIKE` on the timestamp.

Comment: the second's field in timestamps varies. That's why I had to compare only hours and minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  t1.site_id,
  t1.contract_id,
  t1.temp_time,
  AVG(t2.value)
FROM 
  SiteReading AS t1
LEFT JOIN 
  SiteReading AS t2
ON 
  t1.site_id = t2.site_id 
  AND t2.datetime BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
  AND HOUR(t1.temp_time) = HOUR(t2.temp_time) 
  AND MINUTE(t1.temp_time) = MINUTE(t2.temp_time)
WHERE 
  t1.temp_time BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
GROUP BY
  t1.site_id,
  t1.contract_id,
  t1.temp_time
```

Not tested at all but something like this may serve you better.
Optimisations I made:

1. Use a single self join on the matching time interval.
2. Use group by with average aggregate
3. Restricting first table to a subset between your 5 day period (startdate, enddate)
4. Not joining on Site or Contract. You have foreign keys for these tables in Baseline, so no need pull extra data from these tables (I'm assuming programme came from one of these).

> 1.Because I need to get some additional values (site_id, contract_id, programme) to store in the Baseline that are the same for each row I was wondering that maybe I should do the insert statement in some other way? the thing is that all of the Baseline table's columns can not be null.

See #4

> 2.Maybe someone has any other comments about this procedure - do I need to define some other parameters for this routine like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or some other routine related things?

Not sure I completely understand your requirements here. Are you collecting multiple 5 day baselines over a longer period? If so I don't understand why you would need to update anything. If some of the temp_time overlap (ie you run your procedure more frequently than every 5 days for a 5 day period) then you could keep an unique id or timestamp as part of the baseline primary key identifying when you ran the procedure to prevent duplicate keys on the temp_time.

### Edit

I just see now that your days may not be consecutive. in which case change these lines:

```
AND t2.datetime BETWEEN startdate AND enddate

t1.temp_time BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

to:

```
AND DATE(t2.datetime) IN (day1, day2, day3, day4, day5)

DATE(t1.temp_time) IN (day1, day2, day3, day4, day5)
```

However, this poses a problem as you must now do a full table scan of sitereading in the WHEREclause and ON condition. 
To avoid this you could consider normalising the time interval for your dataset before storing it. Eg if 24*60 readings are taken a day then each temp_time interval can be represented by an int from 1 to 1440,  and each day can be represented by an int from 1 to 365 (366 leap year). Then use these values in your where and join clauses instead.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. Now that I think about it there were many things wrong with the query that I wrote initially. First of all, I've made some changes to the apps that write to the SiteReading so there would only be one row for each minute and timestamps would always have 00 in their seconds field - so it's way easier to compare timestamps now (by just getting the time filed). I have rewritten the query in a way better and efficient manner as well:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `calc_baseline2`(IN `input_site_id` int, IN `day1` char(12), IN `day2` char(12), IN `day3` char(12), IN `day4` char(12), IN `day5` char(12))
BEGIN

DECLARE curr_date char(10) DEFAULT cast(date(CURRENT_DATE()) as char(10));

insert into Baseline
SELECT distinct
    SR.site_id as site_id,
    S.contract_id as contract_id,
    concat(cast(date(CURRENT_DATE()) as char(10)), ' ',cast(time(temp_time) as char(8))) as timestamp,
    sum(value) as value,
    programme
FROM
    SiteReading SR
        join
    Site S ON SR.site_id = S.site_id
        join
    Contract C ON S.contract_id = C.contract_id
where
    (temp_time like concat(day1,'%')
        or temp_time like concat(day2,'%')
        or temp_time like concat(day3,'%')
        or temp_time like concat(day4,'%')
        or temp_time like concat(day5,'%'))
        and SR.site_id = input_site_id
group by time(temp_time)
limit 1440;


END
```

again, thank you all for your help :)